# Model options for ARKit

Tags: 3d, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm trying to export model in .dae format to implement in AR. Same with .obj format. But sometimes it is not showing, sometimes model's animation doesn't work.
Are there some working settings of export from 3D Max or Blender?

Answer (score 0):

**Sometimes not showing:** maybe path incorrect, or sometimes the asset is not properly copied into the project folder (at different place). If you use the template ARKit from Apple, and simply bring in your OBJ or DAE it should work. Watch out if the object is too big, maybe you need to move around your iOS device to finally see the object.

**Sometimes model animation does not work:** well... depends how you do it. Maybe record the process as video and upload to YouTube so we know where the mistake is.

DAE animation can be tricky to export correctly from Blender. If the DAE in Blender failed to export the animation, use "Better Collada Export IO" from Godot Engine.

Read some materials here regarding DAE and SceneKit, and it will help you to export DAE for ARKit.
http://saltpigmedia.com/blog/First-steps-in-SceneKit